# Multiple counts on same table (Laravel)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I need to count several values from the same table. I am currently repeating each query and just modifying the `where()` clause. This works, but is hardly using a DRY approach.

In my controller here is my current method for calling a returning each required count:

```
$one = DB::table('stores')->where('store_id', '1')->count();
$two = DB::table('stores')->where('store_id', '2')->count();
$three = DB::table('stores')->where('store_id', '3')->count();
$four = DB::table('stores')->count();
$dutch = DB::table('stores')->where('country', 'Netherlands')->count();
$swedish = DB::table('stores')->where('country', 'Sweden')->count();

return View::make('retailers.index', compact('one','two','three', 'four', 'dutch','swedish'));
```

My view, I call like so:

```
{{ $one }}, {{ $two }}, {{ $three }} etc etc
```

Is there a more suitable approach here then having to make a query for every count to the one table? Any solutions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the following query:

```
$results= DB::table('stores')
             ->select('store_id', DB::raw('count(*) as count'))
             ->groupBy('store_id')
             ->get();
```

Now in your view, you can loop through it.

```
@foreach($results as $result)
  {{  $result->store_id  }} 
  {{  $result->count  }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: Can you provide me an example with loop in view?

Comment: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array.

Answer (score 0):

You could run something along the lines of

```
SELECT count(*), store_id FROM myTable GROUP BY store_id
```

Comment: Correct, however how do i combat the value other than store_id, eg: `country` etc.

Comment: Check Jilson's answer. It is more correct and uses PHP syntax rather than plain SQL

Comment: What do you mean combat?